# Getting 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning' when using the 'store' field in express-session

Tags: node.js, passport.js, cloudant, express-session

I am using 'express-session' to enable persistent login on my site. Everything works perfectly, but when I use an external database to store the cookies, I get the following warning: 

`(node:6084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
(node:6084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6084) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process wit
h a non-zero exit code.`

I have narrowed it down to be related to the `store` field in the `session` object. Below you will see the code for my `app.use(session{...})`. If I remove the `store` field from this JSON object, it defaults to use `MemoryStore` and the above warning is not thrown. I am using IBM Cloudant DB, which communicates perfectly and saves the session data as expected. The issue is the warning above that is being thrown.

```
// Works, but warning is thrown
app.use(session({
    store: store, // Use the IBM Cloudant database as a store.
    resave: true, // Store sessions back to the store if they were never modified. 
    saveUninitialized: true, // Save any uninitialized or new sessions that have no data.
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
        secure: true
    }
}));

// Works with no warning being thrown.
app.use(session({
    resave: true, // Store sessions back to the store if they were never modified. 
    saveUninitialized: true, // Save any uninitialized or new sessions that have no data.
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
        secure: true
    }
}));
```

Here is my Cloudant setup, it works perfectly and always returns `Session connected`, because it connects properly.

```
// Create the session storage object to store cookies.
const store = new CloudantStore({
    url: CLOUDANT_DB_URL,
    database: DB_NAME
});

// Inform us that the session is connected to the cloudant database.
store.on('connect', () => console.log('Session connected'));
// Inform us that the session disconnected from the cloudant database.
store.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Session disconnected.'));
// Inform us that the session failed to connect to the cloudant database.
store.on('error', (err) => console.log(err.msg));
```

The expected result is for the session to work without the above warning being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think it has anything to do with your code, most likely it's a library you are using.

The error is because a promise is written without a catch. If you are new to promises I suggest reading up on how they work first.

Currently if a promise fails and doesn't have a catch it never resolves, which will probably not crash your program, but will prevent it from properly continuing.

Some coders leave off the .catch() from a promise they never expect to fail. This is not good practice, and in future versions of Node, it will prevent code with promises missing catches from running. For now you are fine, but you should figure out what library is causing this error and alert the author so it can be updated.

If you want to fix it yourself, it is as simple as adding:

```
.catch((error)=>{console.log("The promise failed! error: "+error)})
```

to the promise, keep in mind this won't solve issue related to the promise not returning the expected data, but you can also add in logic with how to deal with that.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the advice, I will do just that.

Comment: @CtrlAltDelete I'm guilty of leaving off catches as well. Added example of a quick fix.